# How can I join two tables to get an output in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I'm trying to calculate the overall value of a transaction by doing amount*price_for_each.

As an example, 5 Garlic, 8 Bread,1 Chicken and 1 Rice. The price of (from Items) of Garlic is 25, Bread is 200,Chicken is 450and Rice is 200. 5⋅25+8⋅200+1⋅450+1⋅200=2125

```
CREATE TABLE Items(
price_for_each INT,
name VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

CREATE TABLE ItemsInTransactions(
name VARCHAR(20),
t_id INT,
amount INT,
FOREIGN KEY(name) references Items(name),
FOREIGN KEY(t_id) references Transactions(t_id)
);

CREATE VIEW TransactionValue AS
SELECT DISTINCT t_id,sum(amount*price_for_each) as value
FROM Items price_for_each, ItemsInTransactions amount 
GROUP BY t_id
ORDER BY t_id;
```

I believe the problem is in my view, the outputted values are much higher than anticipated which leads me to believe there is an arithmetic error (maybe multiplying too much). If anyone can explain a better way to calculate my output this would be greatly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdwXO.png)

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates. (As a matter of fact, that combination raises many eyebrows...)

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Comment: Do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers. [help] [meta.se] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

`FROM Items price_for_each, ItemsInTransactions amount` is the old deprecated way to do a cross join (producing every combination of Items and ItemsInTransactions records).  You want an inner join instead:

```
FROM ItemsInTransactions amount
INNER JOIN Items price_for_each on price_for_each.name=amount.name
```

so you are only looking up the price for each for the item in question.

Some other comments:  DISTINCT is redundant here, your group by already assures you will only have one row for each t_id.  table aliases should help document what your query is doing or just allow you to refer to table fields more tersely; here you are using aliases that describe what you are getting from the table, which isn't particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

you a re using a cross join which will combine all available crows

Better is always to use joins

```
CREATE VIEW TransactionValue AS
SELECT t_id,sum(amount*price_for_each) as value
FROM Items i JOIN  ItemsInTransactions iit ON i.name  = iit.name 
GROUP BY t_id
ORDER BY t_id;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i seem to get the right output with this method. On a side note, i just edited my question with an error that i am still recieving. Can you spot the syntax error that i have anywhere?

Comment: for that i must see the original but it should work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2cedda8c16136b0a747847cae716443  if you mean your query, it makes no sense what you write that is why use my rewrite